# Fragment crashes after being in background

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, fragment

I have this problem. I have an activity and a fragment inside it. I am downloading some data using async task in activity's `onCreate` and then using it in the fragment's `onCreate` (something like `getActivity().getData()`). I am putting the fragment into a view after the data is loaded so it runs without trouble. The problem is that when I'm relaunching the activity from background and this fragment is active it loads immediately and throws an NullPointerException because the data isnt loaded yet. My idea was to check for this in the fragment's `onCreate` and if I get null data I'll just destroy it and call some activity's method for reloading data and then lauch the fragment again - is it even possible?
Do you have any solution for this or maybe a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's possible to cache the data on the phone, I would consider it.

If you have to reload the data on every (re-)start (more like: every resume) of the app, take a look at the activity lifecycle in the android documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Your problem should be solved, if you @Overwrite onResume() of your activity and load your data there, instead of onCreate()